# JavaScript - wrap an object in an html container before appending

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I am using a popup lightbox plugin, the plugin generates next/prev buttons but it doesn't put them in a container. I would like to wrap them in a containing element and have found the spot in the plugin where they are generated but I can't figure out how to wrap them since they are generated as an object.

This is what the default code for button generation looks like:

```
mfp.container.append(arrowLeft.add(arrowRight));
```

Before adding them to the container I would like to wrap them in a div with the class `mfp-nav`. I tried the following, but it's not working since the buttons are an `object`.

```
mfp.container.append('<div class="mfp-nav">' + arrowLeft.add(arrowRight) + '</div>');
```

On the front-end this ends up looking like this:

```
<div class="mfp-nav">[object Object]</div>
```

Is there an easy way to wrap this object in a container without looping over the object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`arrowLeft` and `arrowRight` are not HTML strings, they're DOM elements, so you can't just concatenate them with other HTML. Create the DOM elements.

```
let div = document.createElement('div');
div.classList.add('mfp-nav');
div.append(arrowLeft.add(arrowRight));
mfp.container.append(div);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using DOM API:

```js
const divElement= document.createElement('div');
divElement.className = 'mfp-nav';
divElement.appendChild(
  arrowLeft.add(arrowRight)
);

mfp.container.append(divElement)
```